# How TraCIMobility determine/control behaviors (i.e., stop at a particular time) of vehicles in SUMO

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

FYI. I know each vehicle in sumo is modeled by a module in OMNET++ that contains a TraCIMobility submodule that includes parameters such as "accidentStart" and "accidentDuration". But it is not clear how TraCIMobility use these parameters to stop vehicles in SUMO. Shouldn't vehicle routes already be defined in the .rou.xml files in SUMO?

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right: vehicle movement is, by default, fully governed by SUMO. There is, however, a way of changing vehicle behavior at runtime, by calling TraCI methods from OMNeT++ (here: causing a vehicle to stop).

Comment: Thanks!!! Could you also point to me which function it is as I haven't found any?

Comment: https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h has a list of all functions. The tutorial simulation calls one of them here: https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L59